# Spring boot, Security, OAuth2: Is possible to use custom AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails? Auth server requires specific params in redirect url

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, single-sign-on, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I'm developing an OAuth2 Client with SpringBoot. A third-party auth server requires specific params in redirect urls.

My app.yml

```
 acme:
    client:
      clientId:     acme
      clientSecret: acmepassword
      accessTokenUri:       http://localhost:8080/sso/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/sso/oauth/authorize
      specificParam1: specific1
      specificParam2: specific2

    resource:
      userInfoUri:    http://localhost:8080/sso/api/me
```

I've created my `CustomClientResourceDetails` by extending from `AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails`.

```
public class CustomClientResourceDetails extends AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails {
    private String specificParam1;
    private String specificParam2;
    ...    
}
```

And @Autowire it in my SecurityConfig. I've also created a custom filter

```
  @Configuration
    @EnableOAuth2Client
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {      
        @Autowired
        OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
         ...
        .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
     }

        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
            FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<OAuth2ClientContextFilter>();
            registration.setFilter(filter);
            registration.setOrder(-100);
            return registration;
        }

        private Filter ssoFilter() {
            OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter customFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(LOGIN);
            OAuth2RestTemplate customTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(custom(), oauth2ClientContext);
            customFilter.setRestTemplate(customTemplate);
            UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(customResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                    custom().getClientId());
            tokenServices.setRestTemplate(customTemplate);
            customFilter.setTokenServices(
                    new UserInfoTokenServices(customResource().getUserInfoUri(), custom().getClientId()));
            return customFilter;
        }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("acme.client")
        @Primary
        public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails custom() {
            return new CustomClientResourceDetails();
        }

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties("acme.resource")
        public ResourceServerProperties customResource() {
            return new ResourceServerProperties();
        }
    }
```

But specific param don't included in redirect url because `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` and the associated with it classes work via `OAuth2RestOperations` or 'OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails' where only default params.

**Is it possible include additional params to redirect urls? And how?**

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you need to send some dynamic parameter while being redirected to authorization page of IDP. In this case, you can extennd `AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider` and override method `getRedirectForAuthorization`. You can add your custom parameter like this:

```
// add all your custom parameter to 'requestParameters'
requestParameters.put("myCustomParameter","myCustomParameterValue");

UserRedirectRequiredException redirectException = new UserRedirectRequiredException(
                    resource.getUserAuthorizationUri(), requestParameters);
```

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I did it in this way. There is the example [link](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-authentication-with-reddit).